# Position:relative bottom:91%, firefox not working

Tags: css, firefox

I have a X (to .hide) a light box. In chrome the x is in the correct position (top right) however when testing in Fire fox, it seems that it ignores it entirely, placing the X instead on the bottom right.

```
 .btn_close{
    background: url( img goes here);
    position: relative;
    bottom: 91%;
    height:25px;
    width:25px;
    background-position:0 0;    
    right: 1.5%;    
}
```

Is there a specific work around for this, or am I missing something key to this. Again it works/looks fine in the chrome version.

Edit: I forgot to mention that it's a light box with a iframe. I think it has to do mostly with the iframe causing a issue (security feature?) By switching it to absolute however it does all the X to move, but it still seems to tuck it under the frame.

Comment: Just a suggestion to simplify this, I would use `top: 9%;` instead. It will do almost exactly what you're already doing and be more readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make `.btn-close`'s position `absolute` and the light box's position `relative`.

Doing what you're doing with `position: relative` will probably work unexpectedly.

For further reading, [Learn CSS Positioning in Ten Steps](http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/)

Answer (score 1):

I personally think it is better practise to make the div containing the btn position:relative and the button itself position absolute. This works in every browser!

Example:

```
    #container{
     Position: relative;
     Width:300px;
     Height:300px;
     Overflow:hidden;
    }

  .btn–close{
     Position:absolute;
     Bottom:10px;
     Right:5px
     ...
   }
```